# Why isn't eliminate_zeros() removing the zero entries?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

### Code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

arr = np.array([[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [1,0,1]])
mat = csr_matrix(arr)
mat.eliminate_zeros()
print(mat.toarray())
```

---

### Output

```
[[0 0 0]
[0 0 1]
[1 0 2]]
```

---

According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.eliminate_zeros.html), this method removes the zero entries from the matrix. However, why are there still zeros?

From this [website](https://newbedev.com/scipy-sparse-set-row-to-zeros), I've gathered the following:

> `eliminate_zeros` removes all zeros in your matrix from the sparsity pattern (ie. there is no value stored for that position, when before there was a vlaue stored, but it was 0).

I can still access those zero entries.

```
print(mat[0, 0])
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation should probably be more explicit. `eliminate_zeros` doesn't affect the logical contents of a sparse matrix at all.

`eliminate_zeros` changes the underlying representation of a sparse matrix without affecting its logical contents. It removes *explicitly stored* zeros from the data array backing the sparse matrix. It's used to reduce space consumption, and to prepare a sparse matrix for algorithms that assume there will be no explicitly stored zeros.

It does not remove logical zeros from the sparse matrix. That wouldn't be possible - you can't have a sparse matrix with a bunch of data-less holes in it. It's not like a masked array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand what you mean by saying, "explicitly stored."

Comment: @Nameless: A sparse matrix representation says what values are in what cells, and any cell that doesn't have an explicit value associated with it is implicitly 0. However, it's possible for a sparse matrix to *explicitly* store a 0 value for cells instead of leaving it implicit. `eliminate_zeros` removes such explicit zeros.

Comment: What is an "explicit value"?

Comment: @Nameless: Imagine the underlying representation of a sparse matrix says "index 1, 2 has value 5; index 5, 3 has value 0; index 6, 6 has value -12". These are explicit stored values, and the 0 at index 5, 3 is explicit when zeros would usually be implicit. `eliminate_zeros` would remove the explicit entry for index 5, 3.

Comment: If it removes the explicit entry for that index, why am I able to acess it using that index?

Comment: We're getting beyond the scope of the question. I suggest reading up on sparse matrix representations, and maybe looking at the scipy.sparse source and how implementing operators works in Python.

Comment: The quoted documentation does talk about "the sparsity pattern".  This is the equivalent of your "logical contents".  I tried to demonstrate the underlying changes made by `eliminate_zeros`.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the other answer, I'll show the underlying data storage of your sparse matrix.

```
In [147]: from scipy import sparse
In [148]: arr = np.array([[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [1,0,1]])
```

The `coo` format is easiest to understand

```
In [149]: M = sparse.coo_matrix(arr)
In [150]: M
Out[150]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [151]: print(M)
  (1, 2)    1
  (2, 0)    1
  (2, 2)    1
```

The values are actually stored in 3 arrays:

```
In [152]: M.data,M.row,M.col
Out[152]: 
(array([1, 1, 1]),
 array([1, 2, 2], dtype=int32),
 array([2, 0, 2], dtype=int32))
```

`csr` format changes the `row/col` arrays:

```
In [153]: Mr = M.tocsr()
In [154]: Mr.data, Mr.indices, Mr.indptr
Out[154]: 
(array([1, 1, 1]),
 array([2, 0, 2], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 0, 1, 3], dtype=int32))
```

Now let's change one element of the `data` array:

```
In [155]: Mr.data[1] = 0
In [156]: Mr.data
Out[156]: array([1, 0, 1])
```

`eliminate_zeros` finds that 0, and removes it from the data structure:

```
In [157]: Mr.eliminate_zeros()
In [158]: Mr.data
Out[158]: array([1, 1])
In [159]: Mr.indices
Out[159]: array([2, 2], dtype=int32)
In [160]: Mr.A
Out[160]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1]])
In [161]: print(Mr)       # show the coo style values
  (1, 2)    1
  (2, 2)    1
```

Changing the `indices` and `indptr` of a `csr` (changing the "the sparsity pattern") is more work than simply assigning 0 to the `data`.  So the `csr` format lets you make a bunch of changes to `data`, and cleaning up afterwards.

Anyways, this `eliminate_zeros` is not something a beginning user is likely to need.